# Android Navigation Drawer Icon reverting to default when Drawer is open

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I'm having a problem with the Navigation Drawer Icon.
We replaced the default "back caret" to use a different icon and it works fine.

However, if the navigation drawer is already open and the user rotates their device, then the icon reverts back to the default caret and won't go back to the custom one until the navigation drawer is closed and the `onCreate()` method for the activity is called again (usually by rotating the device).

Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    // set the toolbar as the action bar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new StartFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    //Init the GameLog
    GameLog.init(this);
}

/**
 * Initializes the DrawerLayout for the particular activity
 */
public static void init(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)activity.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    //set adapter
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    //set layout manager
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    //add a divider between elements
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(
            new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(activity)
                    .color(Color.WHITE)
                    .build());

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)((ActionBarActivity)activity).getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(activity, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (activity.getActionBar() != null) {
        activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        activity.getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    GameLog.getToggle().syncState();
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into calling `ActionBarDrawerToggle#syncState`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#syncState()

Comment: The syncState() method is called in the onPostCreate, so it should be called after the device is rotated and the activity is recreated.